# L.Polygon getting distorted when panning a map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, maps

I am using Mapbox with leaflet. I have drawn a simple polygon with a hole inside that polygon. I have done this using L.polygon and passing an array of points inside it and another array in reverse direction creating a hole as mentioned in the API docs of leaflet [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).
 the output is as shown in the image below[image]

When we pan the map, I don't want that circle to move from it's place on the screen and hence, on panning of map i am redrawing the circle on the center of the map. But the problem is, when i pan the map, the circle gets distorted. I know, map tiles needs time to load but the circle is also getting loaded and hence not giving clear view, as shown in the images

at start of the panning

[image]

and when i keep on dragging

[image]

Then once i finish dragging, the circle is normal again (i.e the overlap of map tiles over the circle goes away). This is giving very bad experience to the user
note: I am showing the hole as kilometers within reach, considering the user is at the centre of the circle

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the clipping of polygons by leaflet.
A solution is to have a non moving hole using CSS in an overlay layer (not managed by leaflet). You still have to adjust the diameter of the circle during the drag depending on the location, but you will avoid this behaviour.

Making a circle hole in css:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-circle-using-only-css

Making an overlay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537496/bootstrap-row-over-leaflet